# Create users to post unplublished nodes so admin could approve

Tags: rules, users

How can I create some users in Drupal 6 to post unpublished nodes so that admin could approve those unpublished node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways.  (**Edit:**The [workbench module](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) is very popular, but is for Drupal 7 only). I have achieved good results using the [revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module, which has a release for Drupal 6.